# iphone json parser and NsmutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, json, asihttprequest, nsmutabledictionary

I got the Response string

```
{"status":200,"response":
 {"data":
  [{"category_name":"Clubs","items":     
     [{"id":"4ee097a59f39d00308000004","name":"Item B","image":"/uploads/item/image/4ee097a59f39d00308000004 /thumb_cyber.png","description":"Thuudd","price":90,"monentary_type":1
     }]
   }],
 "message":"List of all the items"}}
```

This is my string I just Parse

```
pro_Catagory        =   [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"status"];
```

I got the 200
But The following is not working 
Its pointing to Null

```
pro_Status  =   [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"response.data.category_name"];
```

How can i get other values help me...

Comment: you should use http://json.bloople.net/ for better understanding of json structure. Copy and paste your json response and format it.

Comment: your wording of question reminded me Raj comics. Chacha Choudhari aur Raka ka Aatank.. ,Pinky aur Gilehari..!!. just joking..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use like this:

```
pro_status = [[[[jsonDictionary valueForKey:response] valueForKey:data] objectAtIndex:1] valueForKey:@"category_name];
```

Comment: pro_status = [[[[jsonDictionary valueForKey:@"response"] valueForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"category_name"]; This will works.